# String manipulation in Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

VF

```
<apex:page standardController="Expense__c" extensions="test_e" >
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
 <!-- <h1> ExpenseChild's CLText Field Content : </h1> -->
  <br/>
  <!-- <h2> {!s} </h2> -->
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <apex:pageBlockSection >
  <apex:pageblocktable width="800px" value="{!s}" var="ele_s">
  <apex:column value="{!ele_s.Id}" />
  <apex:column value="{!ele_s.Name}" />
  <apex:column value="{!ele_s.EC_Pick__c}" />
  <apex:column value="{!ele_s.CLText__c}" /> //Line X
  </apex:pageblocktable>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputLink>-->
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class test_e {

public String s;
public String child_data;
public List<ExpenseChild__c> child_coll = new List<ExpenseChild__c>();

public List<ExpenseChild__c> gets()
{

return child_coll;
}


    public test_e(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {

     s = String.valueOf(ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
     child_coll = [SELECT Id,CLText__c,Name,EC_Pick__c FROM ExpenseChild__c WHERE Expense__c = :s];


    }

}
```

I am wondering whether it is possible to the substringing that i want `(LEN(CLText__c,10))` at VF Markup (Line X in VF) instead of doing the substringing at the controller level.

I tried the following and I am not getting the substringing done..instead it displays `LEN("+CLText__c`.

```
<apex:column value="LEN({!ele_s.CLText__c},100)" />
```

Can someone let me know how to achieve a substring operation done at the markup level instead at controller ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the function inside of the expression.

The LEN function outputs the length of the String input:

```
<apex:column value="{!LEN(ele_s.CLText__c)}" />
```

You might want to look at the LEFT or RIGHT functions, or some composition of all of them, depending what it is that you are trying to achieve:

**LEFT**

> LEFT(text, num_chars) and replace text with the field or expression you want returned; replace num_chars with the number of characters from the left you want returned.

**RIGHT**

> RIGHT(text, num_chars) and replace text with the field or expression you want returned; replace num_chars with the number of characters from the right you want returned.

**LEN**

> LEN(text) and replace text with the field or expression whose length you want returned.

More on the functions in the [documentation on Visualforce functions](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm).